# Proof of inequalities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I am having trouble with the following exercise:

---

Let $p$ and $n$ denote positive integers. Use the formula $$b^p - a^p = (b-a)(b^{p-1}+b^{p-2}a + \cdots +ba^{p-2} + a^{p-1})$$ to show that $$n^p < \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}{p+1} < (n+1)^p.$$

---

I've been trying to find a proof of the inequalities above but every time I am getting stucked with the term $(p+1)$ in the denominator. Could you please provide a hint about that or complete proof?

Comment: Nice moniker!  Check out my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43690/whats-a-mathematician-to-do.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}{p+1}=\frac1{p+1}((n+1)^p+(n+1)^{p-1}n+(n+1)^{p-2}n^2+\dots+n^p)>\frac1{p+1}(n^p+n^{p-1}n+n^{p-2}n^2+\dots+n^p)=\frac1{p+1}(p+1)n^p=n^p.$

Another part is analogous.